# Label format in RefTex

Tags: reftex-mode

I am trying to configure RefTeX/AUCTeX so that the smart label-creation, invoked with `C-c (` has the following sets of behaviors:

- for \section-type labels, i.e., for \section, \subsection, etc. generate a label of the form: `\label{sec:[[derived-from-section-name]]}` where what follows the colon is derived from the section name.
- for \items in an enumerate environment, generate a label of the form: `\label{item:[[number]]}`, where the number is automatically incremented from what has gone before. i.e., the first enumerate item I generate a label for gets `\label{item:1}`, the next one `\label{item:2}`, and so on.

This was standard behavior of my reftex implementation when I was using aquamacs, but I haven't been able to duplicate this in standard emacs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RefTeX has a variable called `reftex-insert-label-flags`.  From the docstring:

> `reftex-insert-label-flags` is a variable defined in `reftex-vars.el`.
>   Its value is `("s" "sft")`
>   Documentation:
>   Flags governing label insertion.  First flag DERIVE, second flag
>   PROMPT.
>
> If DERIVE is t, RefTeX will try to derive a sensible label from
>   context. A section label for example will be derived from the section
>   heading. The conversion of the context to a valid label is governed by
>   the specifications given in `reftex-derive-label-parameters`. If
>   RefTeX fails to derive a label, it will prompt the user. If DERIVE is
>   nil, the label generated will consist of the prefix and a unique
>   number, like `eq:23`.
>
> If PROMPT is t, the user will be prompted for a label string.  The
>   prompt will already contain the prefix, and (if DERIVE is t) a default
>   label derived from context.  When PROMPT is nil, the default label
>   will be inserted without query.
>
> So the combination of DERIVE and PROMPT controls label insertion. 
>   Here is a table describing all four possibilities:
>
> ```
> DERIVE   PROMPT  ACTION
> nil      nil     Insert simple label, like eq:22 or sec:13.  No query. 
> nil      t       Prompt for label.
> t        nil     Derive a label from context and insert without query.
> t        t       Derive a label from context and prompt for confirmation.
> ```
>
> Each flag may be set to t, nil, or a string of label type letters
>   indicating the label types for which it should be true.  The strings
>   work like character classes. Thus, the combination may be set
>   differently for each label type.  The default settings "s" and "sft"
>   mean: Derive section labels from headings (with confirmation).  Prompt
>   for figure and table labels.  Use simple labels without confirmation
>   for everything else. The available label types are: s (section), f
>   (figure), t (table), i (item), e (equation), n (footnote), N
>   (endnote), plus any definitions in ‘reftex-label-alist’.

With the standard setting, you should achieve what you're asking for.  Check the value and if it's somehow changed somewhere.